# Cometd : It seems that ServerChannel lose some subscribers

Tags: cometd

I used cometd to realize notification push, but i found out the following issue :
After log in the system, at the beginning, the client can receive message from server, but after wait pretty long time or do some other operation, the client may not receive message from server any more. Did anyone else encountered this problem? Thanks in Advance.
Blow is my code :
1. Client Code

```
var cometd = dojox.cometd;cometd.websocketEnabled = false;
    cometd.init(url);
    cometd.subscribe("/foo/new", function(message) {
            ......The business logic......
        }
    );
```

2. The ServletContextAttributeListener that integrate with AbstractService

```
public class BayeuxInitializerListener implements ServletContextAttributeListener {
private static final String CLIENT_CHANNEL = "/foo/new";
@Override
public void attributeAdded(ServletContextAttributeEvent event) {
    if(BayeuxServer.ATTRIBUTE.equals(event.getName())) {
        BayeuxServer bayeuxServer = (BayeuxServer) event.getValue();
        boolean isCreated = bayeuxServer.createIfAbsent(CLIENT_CHANNEL, new ConfigurableServerChannel.Initializer() {
            @Override
            public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel) {
                channel.setPersistent(true);
            }
        });
        new MyService(bayeuxServer);

    }
}
```

3. Service

```
public class MyService extends AbstractService {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyService .class);

private static final String CLIENT_CHANNEL = "/foo/new";
private static final String LISTENER_CHANNEL = "/service/notification";

public MyService(BayeuxServer bayeuxServer) {
    super(bayeuxServer, "notification");
    this.addService(LISTENER_CHANNEL, "processNotification");
}

public void processNotification(ServerSession serverSession, Map<String, Object> data) {
    LocalSession localSession = this.getLocalSession();
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Local Session : " + localSession.getId() + ".");
    }
    ServerChannel serverChannel = this.getBayeux().getChannel(CLIENT_CHANNEL)
    Set<ServerSession> subscribers = serverChannel.getSubscribers();
    if(0 == subscribers.size()) {
        logger.info("There are no subcribers for " + CLIENT_CHANNEL + ".");
    }
    for(ServerSession subscriber : subscribers) {
        logger.info("The subscriber for " + CLIENT_CHANNEL + " : " + subscriber.getId() + ".");
    }
    serverChannel.publish(localSession, data, null);
}
```

Comment: what CometD version, what servlet container vendor and exact version ? The code you posted is good.

Comment: Cometd2.4.0, Websphere 7, but i use servlet2.5 specification not 3.0.

Comment: I noticed cometd 2.4.0 reference document says :<br/>1. The server channel sweeper will sweep channels that are non-persistent, have no subscribers, have no listeners, have no authorizers and have no children channels, and only after these conditions are met for three consecutive sweeper passes.<br/>2. You can not only configure ServerChannel instances to be persistent, but to be lazy.<br/>I am suspicious that whether it is related to 2th option.

Comment: your code is correct, you don't need to make the channel also lazy, it's persistent and that's enough.
I think you're hitting a Websphere problem or a misconfiguration. Are you using the ContinuationFilter ?

Comment: About the ContinuationFilter, see updated documentation at http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_configuration_servlet_25

Comment: have you had any advance on this?

Comment: Hi Oso, in our system, there are 2 application.

Comment: Hi Oso, in our system, there are 2 application (client and service). client is based on dojo, and cometd servlet is in the service app. if service app is restarted and client not, the subscribers will be losed. Now i seperate cometd service as standlone app.