# Cometd Push Notification after Network Failure

Tags: cometd, bayeux

Cometd Push Notification cannot succeed after resume of either client or server. 
Not clear about this post. 
[Cometd : It seems that ServerChannel lose some subscribers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310730/cometd-it-seems-that-serverchannel-lose-some-subscribers).
Any suggestion??

Comment: Your question is unclear, since the title refer to network failures, but the description talks about "resume" which is an overloaded term and has a different meaning in CometD - it does not refer to network failures.

Answer (score 0):

CometD push notifications **do** work after network failures, provided that subscriptions are coded correctly as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#javascript_subscribe_vs_listen).